# Plotting all data in Databricks (Scala)

Tags: scala, dataframe, plot, databricks

I'm working in Databricks using Scala and I have a dataframe:

[image: dataframe]

that I would like to do a simple time series plot of. However DBX only shows the first 1000 rows by default:

[image]

I swear there was an option to aggregate across ALL data, however it disappeared and I can't figure out how to do this.

There may be a simple way, can anyone help me out? I could use matplotlib if this were Python, but unfortunately I'm new to Scala.

Comment: You can use Python too :) create a Temp Table from that scala DF. df.createOrReplaceTempView("df_sql") ; spark.read.table(df_sql) and you are free to use Python from here

Comment: that's smart, i'll try that when i get back to working on this!

Comment: hehe - That's the beauty of databricks indeed